# ReadProcessMemory unable to read large number of bytes at once

Tags: c, memory

I am making a memory reading software and am using C. Using the ReadMemoryProcess() method, I am accessing memory. It works fine for when I'm getting low amount of bytes but seems to freeze/pause the code when attempting to access large amounts. Here is my code and it is not the best because I made it in a hurry however the poorly written code does not seem to be the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string.h>

BOOL GetProcessList() {
    char targetname[]="increment.exe";
    int bufferval=2064300;
    SIZE_T noBsize=bufferval-1;

    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    DWORD dwPriorityClass;

    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    if( hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        printf("cth32ss");
        return 1;
    }

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

    if( !Process32First( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) ) {
        printf("Process32First");
        CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );
        return 1;   
    }

    do {
        if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile,targetname)==0) {
            DWORD procID=pe32.th32ProcessID;
            printf("%lu",procID);
            printf("%s",pe32.szExeFile);

            HANDLE CGFProcess=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,procID);
            if (CGFProcess==NULL) {
                printf("OPEN PROCESS FAIL");
                CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );
                return 1;
            }
            printf("success\n");

            HANDLE hModuleSnap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
            MODULEENTRY32 me32;

            hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPMODULE,procID);

            if( hModuleSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
                printf("module snap error");
                CloseHandle(hModuleSnap);
                return 1;
            }

            me32.dwSize = sizeof( MODULEENTRY32 );

            if( !Module32First( hModuleSnap, &me32 ) ) {
                printf("Module32First");
                CloseHandle(hModuleSnap);
                return 1;
            }
            
            LPCVOID baseaddr=NULL;

            do {
                if (strcmp(me32.szModule,targetname)) {
                    printf("MODULE FOUND");
                    baseaddr=(const void*)me32.modBaseAddr;
                    printf("MODSIZE:%i\n",me32.modBaseSize);
                    break;
                }
            } while( Module32Next(hModuleSnap, &me32));
            CloseHandle(hModuleSnap);

            int buffer[bufferval];
            int* bufferp=(int *)&buffer;

            BOOL ReadMem=ReadProcessMemory(CGFProcess,baseaddr,bufferp,noBsize,NULL);
            printf("READ MEM:%i\n",ReadMem);
            FILE* FILE_PTR;
            FILE_PTR=fopen("procmem2.txt","w");
            int k;
            for (k=0;k<noBsize;k++) {
                printf("%i",buffer[k]);
                printf(" ");
                fprintf(FILE_PTR,"%i",buffer[k]);
                fprintf(FILE_PTR," ");
            }
            fclose(FILE_PTR);
            CloseHandle(CGFProcess);
            break;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap,&pe32));

    CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );
    return 0;
}

int main( void ) {
  GetProcessList();
  return 0;
}
```

its a lot of code but most of it can be ignored. The bufferval is basically the amount of bytes I am accessing from the ReadProcessMemory() function. It is not just a random number I guessed but using the MODULEENTRY32 object (me32), I printed out me32.modBaseSize and then manually inserted it as the bufferval.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I'm asking how I can solve the issue I'm facing with the ReadProcessMemory function being unable to read a large amount of bytes.